# Unity check if 2D objects in an array collide without OnCollisionEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have Rigidbody2D and 2D colliders attached to my GameObjects. Is there a way to check if there is a collision between any two of my objects? I found a way: method OnCollisionEnter(), but I want to check for collision in a specific time between specific objects, but not between all. Is there a way to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to check the name or tag of the other object in the OnCollisionEnter() function. https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/detecting-collisions-oncollisionenter

Comment: But if I have an array of objects and in a specific time i want to check if some of them collides using "foreach" cycle. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can. What colliders are they using?

Comment: Circle collider 2D and Box Collider 2D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if there is a collision between any two of my
>   objects?

To check if two 2D Colliders are touching/colliding without `OnCollisionEnter`, use [`Collider2D.IsTouching`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouching.html).

For example:

```
BoxCollider2D myBoxCollider1 = null;
BoxCollider2D myBoxCollider2 = null;

if (myBoxCollider1.IsTouching(myBoxCollider2))
{

}
```

For arrays, this is bit complicated. You have to loop and compare each one with another one. You **must** check if two obejcts has already been compared and not compare them again to prevent multiple collison detection.

For example, in the for loop, if you don't do this you will get:

- Object A is colliding with Object B

then

- Object B is colliding with Object A.

You don't want this. You only want to detect and report collsion between two Objects once.

`Dictionary` would have been the solution to store the detected Objects so that we don't detect them again, but `Dictionary` cannot hold the-same key multiple times.

You can use `List` and `KeyValuePair` to do this. Just peform loop inside another loop and make andthe use `IsTouching` to do the comparism. Before you compare each `BoxCollider2D`, check if both of them already exist in the `List<KeyValuePair>`. If they do, don't compare, if they don't, compare them then add them to do `List<KeyValuePair>`. After you are done comparing them or at the end of the function, clear the list.

```
//Plug in from the Editor
public Collider2D[] myBoxColliders = null;

List<KeyValuePair<Collider2D, Collider2D>> usedCollider = new List<KeyValuePair<Collider2D, Collider2D>>();

void checkArrayCollision()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myBoxColliders.Length; i++)
    {
        checkCollision(i, ref usedCollider);
    }
    //Reset List for next function call
    usedCollider.Clear();
}

void checkCollision(int currentIndex, ref List<KeyValuePair<Collider2D, Collider2D>> usedCollider)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myBoxColliders.Length; i++)
    {
        //Make sure that this two Colliders are not the-same
        if (myBoxColliders[currentIndex] != myBoxColliders[i])
        {
            //Now, make sure we have not checked between this 2 Objects
            if (!checkedBefore(usedCollider, myBoxColliders[currentIndex], myBoxColliders[i]))
            {
                if (myBoxColliders[currentIndex].IsTouching(myBoxColliders[i]))
                {
                    //FINALLY, COLLISION IS DETECTED HERE, call ArrayCollisionDetection
                    ArrayCollisionDetection(myBoxColliders[currentIndex], myBoxColliders[i]);
                }
                //Mark it checked now
                usedCollider.Add(new KeyValuePair<Collider2D, Collider2D>(myBoxColliders[currentIndex], myBoxColliders[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}

bool checkedBefore(List<KeyValuePair<Collider2D, Collider2D>> usedCollider, Collider2D col1, Collider2D col2)
{
    bool checkedBefore = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < usedCollider.Count; i++)
    {
        //Check if key and value exist and vice versa
        if ((usedCollider[i].Key == col1 && usedCollider[i].Value == col2) ||
                (usedCollider[i].Key == col2 && usedCollider[i].Value == col1))
        {
            checkedBefore = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return checkedBefore;
}

void ArrayCollisionDetection(Collider2D col1, Collider2D col2)
{
    Debug.Log(col1.name + " is Touching " + col2.name);
}
```

**Usage**:

Simply call  `checkArrayCollision();` to check which Colliders in the `myBoxColliders` array are colliding with each other.

```
void Update()
{
    checkArrayCollision();
}
```

Each time a collsion is detected, the `ArrayCollisionDetection(Collider2D col1, Collider2D col2)` function will be called and you will receive both colliders that are colldiong in its `col1` and `col2` parameter.

Note:

You mentioned *Circle Collider 2D* and *Box Collider 2D* but this example used `Collider2D` because *Collider2D* is the base of class of both of them and will therefore work with them. So, you can drag *Circle Collider 2D* and *Box Collider 2D* to the `myBoxColliders` slot.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an array that stores links to objects collided with this object, and then just add links in `OnCollisionEnter` and remove links in `OnCollisionExit`. So you will be able to check if one object's array contain link to the second, if it is - these two objects are collided in this moment.